# Is there any RDBMS which supports inserting into joined tables? (multi-table inserts)

Tags: sql, insert, rdbms, database

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table1 inner join table2 on table2.parent=table1.id values(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least one. http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=209
..excerpt...

```
  1    INSERT ALL
  2     INTO t1
  3     INTO t2
  4     INTO t3
  5     INTO t4
  6  SELECT owner
  7  ,      object_type
  8  ,      object_name
  9  ,      object_id
 10  ,      created
 11  FROM   all_objects;
```

Use of views and triggers can do it as well. http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/663921-update-multiple-tables-via-view.html

....Excerpt from above...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgInsteadOfUpdate ON dbo.Someview
INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS 

UPDATE Person 
SET Person = inserted.Person_Name
FROM inserted 

UPDATE Company
SET Company =  inserted.Company_Name 
FROM inserted 

GO
```

There may be other ways; but that's the two I was aware of.

Comment: Can you include some information from the article. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Done and thanks for the link...  though one needs to be careful of copyright and plagerism with that technique.

Comment: what am I selecting with that SELECT owner
  7  ,      object_type
  8  ,      object_name
  9  ,      object_id
 10  ,      created
 11  FROM   all_objects;

Comment: I'm not understanding the comment.  perhaps update the question with relevant details on what you are trying to accomplish.  The initial questions is are there any; not how to.

Comment: @xQbert I'm not a lawyer so I can't really speak to the copyright issue. That said if you're not comfortable quoting a source you can stick with just a link but it may be downvoted, flagged as not an answer, and converted to a comment

Comment: Completely understand.  I have no problem being downvoted, it being altered or added as a comment (though  the links do address the question so a comment didn't seem right), or purged.  I'm about attempting to answer the Authors question.  if my peers think it's poor quality; that's their prerogative to vote accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure what you know is true. PostgreSQL supports writable multi-table views via its [rule system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/rules-views.html).